# Python function with two strings - sub-anagram

Tags: python, string

I'm wanting to define a function with two strings that takes two arguments. I'm wanting this to then return true if the first string is a 'sub-anagram' of the second string. The function should only return true if every letter that's in the first string appears at least as many times in the second string.
eg. key is a 'sub-anagram' of keyboard but mouse isn't.

Here's my code so far:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def anagram(str1,str2):
  # string to list
  str1 = list(str1.lower())
  str2 = list(str2.lower())

  #sort list
  str1.sort()
  str2.sort()

  #join list back to string
  str1 = ''.join(str1)
  str2 = ''.join(str2)

  return str1 == str2

print(anagram('trainers', 'strainer'))
```

So far it will return true if both strings are exact anagrams and I am not sure how to change it.

Thankyou

Comment: Python has a very convenient class called `Counter` in the standard `collections` module: `return Counter(str1.lower()) == Counter(str2.lower())`

Comment: It's a great suggestion, but the `==` wouldn't work with the OP's example (`Counter("key")` is not equal to `Counter("keyboard")`. But the idea is very good (just need to make sure that the counts in the second are equal or more than the counts in the first)

Comment: You are right, I didn't read closely enough - only saw the code example...

Comment: @Rsrichdude098, remember that if any of the answers solved your question, it is a good practice that you mark it as accepted (big checkbox to the left of the answer). It'll give you reputation points, it'll give the person that spent time answering it reputation points and most importantly, it'll help future readers see that the answer was helpful. Please take a look to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235 (not only for this post, but for your future questions as well) Cheers **:-)**

Answer (score 2):

As @achampion mentioned, `Counter` is the best way to go about this. To check if string `a` has all the characters to make string `b`:

```
from collections import Counter

def contains_anagram(a, b):
    a = Counter(a)
    b = Counter(b)
    return all(b[letter] <= a[letter] for letter in b)
```